# Git: show message when cloning

Tags: git, azure-devops

When I clone a repository from my Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) account I obtain a message in the console during cloning itself:

```
Cloning into 'thirdparty/boost'...
remote:
remote:                    vSTs
remote:                  vSTSVSTSv
remote:                vSTSVSTSVST
remote: VSTS         vSTSVSTSVSTSV
remote: VSTSVS     vSTSVSTSV STSVS
remote: VSTSVSTSvsTSVSTSVS   TSVST
remote: VS  tSVSTSVSTSv      STSVS
remote: VS   tSVSTSVST       SVSTS
remote: VS tSVSTSVSTSVSts    VSTSV
remote: VSTSVST    SVSTSVSTs VSTSV
remote: VSTSv        STSVSTSVSTSVS
remote:                VSTSVSTSVST
remote:                  VSTSVSTs
remote:                    VSTs    (TM)
remote:
remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Services
remote:
Receiving objects: 100% (13740/13740), 736.66 MiB | 278.00 KiB/s, done.
```

I'd like to do a similar thing in my git server. How can I send a message to be printed when cloning?

Comment: what is your git server? pure git? butbucket? github? gitolite? gitlab? etc... which version? do you use ssh?

Comment: It's a pure git server running Ubuntu. I use ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no some hook that you can use, but in case you use `ssh` you can print the banner to stderr using this code:

```
cat 1>&2 << "banner"
remote:  _   _      _ _        __        __         _     _
remote: | | | | ___| | | ___   \ \      / /__  _ __| | __| |
remote: | |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` |
remote: |  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |
remote: |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/     \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_|
banner
```

in one of the following files depends on your ssh usage:

- `/etc/sshrc`
- `~/.ssh/rc`

Comment: @Jepessen looks like. I didn't find anything in git documentation

Comment: Is this somekind of SSH thing?